# Ruby on rails - pagination on search result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I have 2 models, Post and Location, where location has_many posts and post belongs_to location. The search works fine, and the pagination works fine too except the total_entries. It shows more than 10 entries in the result

View search.html:

```
<%= form_tag search_posts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :title, params[:title] %>
        <%= text_field_tag :company, params[:company] %>
        <%= select_tag :location_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Location.all, :id, :name, params[:location_id]), include_blank: true %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Controller post_controller.rb:

```
  def search
    title = params[:title]
    company = params[:company]
    location_id = params[:location_id]
    @posts = Post.search(title, company, location_id)
  end
```

Model Post.rb

```
def self.search(title, company, location_id)
    if location_id.present?

        paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", location_id],
                        :per_page => 20,
                        :order => 'created_at DESC',
                        :page => @page,
                        :total_entries => 10

    else

        paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%"],
                        :per_page => 20,
                        :order => 'created_at DESC',
                        :page => @page,
                        :total_entries => 10                
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter **:per_page** defines entries count on each page. **:total_entries** is entries count that fetching from db in total.

I mean **:per_page** can't be larger than **:total_entries**

Comment: When I click to page 2, the url shows: .../search?company=&location_id=&page=2&title=&utf8=%E2%9C%93 ,and the page show page 1 result...why this happen?

Comment: I think the problem is in this place: **:page => @page** . Where the variable @page from ? You probably should send this variable when you call the **search** method of Post class.

Comment: In the model: **def self.search(title, company, location_id, page) ... :page => page, ... end**. In the controller: **def search ... page = params[:page]; @posts = Post.search(title, company, location_id, page); end**

Comment: Thanks man! Also one more thing to ask, I want to limit the number of search results shown. My code has .last(200) in the condition, but seems not working as it stills shows all results.

Comment: Try **order("id desc").limit(200)** instead of **last(200)**. If it will hot help, give me the code string where you use **last** method

Comment: this is my code: paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", location_id].last(200),
                            :order => "total DESC",
                            :page => page,
                            :per_page => 20

Comment: And if I change to this: **paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", location_id],
                            :limit => 100,
                            :order => "total DESC",
                            :page => page,
                            :per_page => 20**   it shows 100 results per page without limiting total results

Comment: I think that **paginate** method is the wrong place where you put **limit** condition. Try to do it before you call **paginate** method.

Comment: In the controller: **@posts = Post.order("id desc").limit(200).search(title, company, location_id)**
You can also do this in the model if you need. Just insert conditions before **paginate** method.

Comment: I want to insert conditions before paginate method in the model, like this **find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", location_id]).limit(200) paginate :order => "total DESC", :page => page, :per_page => 20** but it doesn't work