# Why is pagination on search result not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

Riding on the previous question: 
[Ruby on rails - pagination on search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424562/ruby-on-rails-pagination-on-search-result/20425515?noredirect=1#20425515)

This is my model:

```
def self.search(title, company, location_id)
    if location_id.present?

        paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", location_id].last(200),
                        :page => @page,
                        :per_page => 20,
                        :order => "total DESC"


    else

        paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%"].last(200),
                        :page => @page,
                        :per_page => 20,
                        :order => "total DESC"

    end
end
```

When I click to page 2, the url shows:

`.../search?company=&location_id=&page=2&title=&utf8=%E2%9C%93`

and the page show page 1 result..

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in this place: `:page => @page` . Where is the variable `@page` from ? You probably should send this variable when you call the `search` method of `Post` class

In the model:

```
def self.search(title, company, location_id, page)
    if location_id.present?

        paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", location_id].last(200),
                        :page => page,
                        :per_page => 20,
                        :order => "total DESC"


else

    paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%"].last(200),
                    :page => page,
                    :per_page => 20,
                    :order => "total DESC"

    end
end
```

In the controller:

```
def search 
  ... 
  page = params[:page]
  @posts = Post.search(title, company, location_id, page);
end
```

Comment: Thanks man! Also one more thing to ask, I want to limit the number of search results shown. My code has .last(200) in the condition, but seems not working as it stills shows all results.

Answer (score 0):

In the model:

```
def self.search(title, company, location_id, page) ... :page => page, ... end
```

In the controller:

```
def search ... page = params[:page]; @posts = Post.search(title, company, location_id, page); end
```